# using explode to get the base url

Tags: php

i have a string which is full url i want to extract the base url from this . i know how to extract the last word from this url but dont know how to extract the base url

i have this code if any one can tell how to extract base url it will be great

```
   <?php
  $c='http://santa.com/modules/music/goojhi/test2.php';
 $city1=end($c); 
 echo $city1;  
  ?>
```

the above code will output test2.php but i want to get http://santa.com

Comment: *Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given*

Comment: `echo 'http://'.parse_url($c, PHP_URL_HOST);` is all you need.

Comment: @AmalMurali you're expecting the scheme to be http only there. Whilst that's the case for the given example it's probably best not to make the assumption and get the scheme from the URL provided.

Comment: @ScottHelme: I agree 100%. It's best not to make assumptions, but I just  wanted to share a different way of doing this, just in case if it helps someone. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$var = parse_url('http://santa.com/modules/music/goojhi/test2.php');
echo $var['host'];
```

It's in the PHP Docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

*Edit*

If you need the http:// or https:// part, try this instead:

```
$var = parse_url('http://santa.com/modules/music/goojhi/test2.php');
echo $var['scheme'] . '://' . $var['host'];
```

Comment: No problem, hope it helped!

Comment: @chetna123 Are you going to accept an answer if it did indeed resolve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url):

```
$components = parse_url('http://santa.com/modules/music/goojhi/test2.php');
var_dump($components);
```

Comment: `$components['port']` in this case would probably throw an `Undefined index` error.

Comment: @AmalMurali Yeah.. The proper code would need more checks.. Don't have time at the moment.. will remove that and maybe later refine